# Is this a good way to implement polymorphism for using arithmetic?

Tags: c#, abstract-class

So I wanted to use polymorphism for using arithmetic.

Thus my first thought was to make an interface for using arithmetic, IAddable and such; But I found on the internet that this was not possible. But a trick came into my mind and now I wonder: is this a nice and fast implementation of polymorphism?

```
    public abstract class RingElement
    {
        public static RingElement operator +(RingElement e1, RingElement e2)
        {
            if (e1 == null)
                return e2;
            if (e2 == null)
                return e1;
            Type type = e1.GetType();
            return (RingElement) type.GetMethod("op_Addition").Invoke(null, new object[] {e1, e2 });
        }

        public static RingElement operator *(RingElement e1, RingElement e2)
        {
            if (e1 == null)
                return e2;
            if (e2 == null)
                return e1;
            Type type = e1.GetType();
            return (RingElement) type.GetMethod("op_Multiply").Invoke(null, new object[] { e1, e2 });
        }
    }
```

I made two RingElements: a doubleElement (just containing a double) and a generic 
`Matrix<T> : RingElement where T : RingElement`
The null handling is to implement the possibility of empty sums or empty products.

Every inherited class of RingElement should have two static methods 
`public static T operator +(T x, T y)
public static T operator *(T x, T y)`

with their own body of implementation, where T is the class type

Comment: You are asking if a single class is an example of polymorphism?

Comment: as you can see at the bottom I implemented two derived classes as well

Comment: What is the connection between this and polymorphism? Also, I don't think anything that involves reflection can be considered nice and fast. Reflection is the slow compared to other operations. Polymorphism is supposed to "just" happen as a result of inheritance. If you are using runtime reflection, that is forced polymorphism.

Comment: The usage is very unclear. I created a `DogRingElement` and a `CarRingElement` that inherit from `RingElement`. I created an instance of each and added them together. I got a `RingElement`. If there's something that should be overridden then it should be declared `abstract` or `virtual`. But what *should* I get when I multiply a dog times a car?

Comment: Thanks for the comments; nice to know it isn't fast, and I'll edit to make more clear how to add them.

Comment: It's impossible to mark a static operator method with either abstract or virtual.

If you multiply two dogs, you get puppies right? ;) Kidding

Comment: Marc Gravell and Job Skeet explored this.  Worth a read: https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html

Comment: updated my answer to account for @ScottHannen valid remark ;-)

Comment: what happen if you 'forget' to implement the required operator in the derived class ?

Comment: I tryed it and got 'NullReferenceException'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will work, the bit using reflection does the trick. It is not type-safe and might not be the most performant way but unfortunately there is not really a completely satisfactory answer to your problem in C# yet.

Here are a couple suggestions you might find useful:

To address the valid concern of Scott Hannen, about being able to add a `DogRingElement : RingElement` to a `CatRingElement : RingElement` you can use the strangely recurring pattern,

```
public abstract class RingElement<T> where T : RingElement<T> { .. }

public class DogRingElement : RingElement<DogRingElement> { .. }
public class CatRingElement : RingElement<CatRingElement> { .. }
```

To help a bit with performance you might try,

```
public static RingElement operator +(RingElement e1, RingElement e2)
{
    return (RingElement) ((dynamic) e1 + (dynamic) e2);
}
```

*This has a somewhat large performance hit at the beginning but gets faster after the first use.*

you could use `dynamic` variables in your Matrix implementation,

```
class Matrix<T>
{
     public static Matrix<T> operator + (Matrix<T> a, Matrix<T> b)
     {
         // check a.M = b.M, a.N = b.N
         var c = new Matrix<T>(a.M, a.N);
         for (var i = 0; i < a.N ; i ++)
         {
             for (var i = 0; i < a.N ; i ++)
             {
                  dynamic x = a[i, j], y = b[i, j];
                  c[i,j] = (T) (x + y);
             }
         }
         return c;
    }
}
```

*The performance is not fantastic first time it is used but gets descent afterwards.*

You could also consider a wrapper class implementing the arithmetic operators, holding a reference to an object implementing an interface with Add, Mult etc.. methods,

```
public interface IRingElem<T>   // strangely recurring pattern
     where T : IRingElem<T>
{
    T Add(T);
}

public class Num<T>
     where T : IRingElem<T>
{
    private readonly T elem;

    public static Num<T> operator + (Num<T> a, Num<T> b)
    {
        return new Num<T>(a.elem.Add(b.elem));
    }

}
```

by implementing explicit cast from `T` to `Num<T>` and implicit cast from `Num<T>` to `T` this is reasonably confortable.

If you are after really good performance you might consider making the wrapper class a `struct` (removing the `readonly` sometimes helps also) and using `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]` everywhere in the wrapper class.

Comment: Did you try my method, to implement for instance a ```ComplexInteger : RingElement```? It works fine on my laptop

Comment: Ah yes you are right I answered a bit quickly, I didn't see the reflection aspect of your solution, that's smart, I will update my answer.

Comment: here you go :-)

Comment: Have you tried not to implement the operator in the derived class (just to see if it is robust)

Comment: Thanks! I have tried that, it gives a null-reference exception (could not find the method).

Comment: did the above help ?

Comment: Yes, it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You are a bit too early )). There are `Type Classes` candidate in `c# 9` ([link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/candidate-features-for-c-sharp-9/)) which would be probably most elegant solution in `c#`.

(If using `f#` is an option, it already has [Statically Resolved Type Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters), and the page under this link exactly shows an example of polymorphism for arithmetic)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I wanted to really use the operators + and *, not just methods Add, Mult and Neg. Also this wouldn't work for matrices (unless with an override perhaps) I think?